# How can I display Loops

Tags: android, loops

I'm beginner in Android.

Is easy to output in Loop in Java.  But is working in xml

```
public class BeeActivity extends Activity {

    TextView Num;
    int []w=new int[20]

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Num = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dis1);

        for (int q = 0; q < 10; q++){
            Num.setText(""+w[q]);
```

On display,  it only show 1 number no matter what.  How to display as loop like Java?

Comment: " only show 1 number" What is the position of the number in the w array that is shown?  Is it the last one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you're a beginner, let's start with good code:

```
Num = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dis1);
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
for (int q = 0; q < 10; q++){
  buffer.append(q);
  buffer.append(",");
}
Num.setText(buffer.toString());
```

While StringBuffer might seem like a bit more overhead, it's a whole lot faster than using String directly!

Answer (score 0):

You have to build a String that contains all the numbers.

```
String str = "";
for (int q = 0; q < 10; q++){ 
   str += " " + w[q]; 
};
Num.setText(str);
```

Comment: Sorry .  I don't even know how to reply properly in here.  Just want to say Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int q = 0; q < 10; q++){
    Num.setText(""+w[q]);
}
```

That will only display one number because you are using `setText` every time, which will erase the previous text. Only the last element will show up.

You can save it to a String and display it after the loop is finished, or you can use `append` to the TextView, like so:

```
for (int q = 0; q < 10; q++){
    Num.append(""+w[q]);
}
```

Comment: Is working.  Thank You to All of you.  You guys are great.  Thank you!!!